# How to tell apart matrix multiplication and element wise multiplication on formulas that have no symbol?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I'm studying machine learning, and often I need to implement math formulas that use no symbols to indicate multiplication between matrix variable, for example $Z = WX + b$

Looking at the formulas I can't seem to understand when that multiplication should be element wise multiplication, and when it should be a matrix multiplication.

I was under the impression that unless the formula included $*$ between variables it referred to a matrix multiplication, but it seems I was wrong. Recently I had to implement the following formula:

[image: this formula]

The correct implementation used element wise multiplication.

But then I had to implement [this formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbPpS.png) where as shown the correct implementation was to use matrix multiplication

**How can I know if I should use element wise multiplication or matrix multiplication when looking at a mathmathical formula?**

Additional information, since someone asked for more context: The first formula is for cross entropy cost (basically a meassure of how far the a machine learning model predictions are from the truth). The second formulas are used for backward propagation (calculating how to modify weights(W) and biases(B) on machine learning).

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen $WX$ to mean element-wise multiplication. In a math context it always means matrix multiplication, at least as far as I have seen.

Comment: The only way is context. The authors' job is to make it clear, for their own interest. If they don't, well ... they didn't do their job and the referees didn't do theirs either.

Comment: @pancini that is in line with what I believed, but the implementation of the linked formula suggests otherwise, and its highly unlikely its wrong. It could be as NDB says, that context is the only way to tell them appart, though I hope that's not the case, since it would make it a dangerous|annoying to implement formulas when you don't fully understand the context.

Comment: "...it would make it a dangerous|annoying to implement formulas when you don't fully understand the context."  Isn't it *always* dangerous to implement other people's code if you don't understand the context in which that code runs?  or when you don't know what the code does?

Comment: Maths are full of things you cannot understand if you don't know the uses and habits of the domain. And the sharper the domain, the more it happens. Additionnally, in data sciences, this is sometimes on purpose: the author wants to get published, but does not want other teams to improve his methods too easily. This is the reason why some people want "reproducibility", where you publish an implementation of your algorithm.

Comment: The mathematical formula seems to be using superscript $(i)$ as an index. What do you think the superscript means? As I read it, it very explicitly says to take the $i$th element of $y$ and multiply by the $i$th element of $a^{[L]}$. Then subtract the $i$th element of $y$ from $1$, and so forth. Looks like element-wise operations to me, unless $y^{(i)}$ itself is a matrix, which can somehow be subtracted from the number $1$. What are the dimensions of $y$?

Comment: Is the numpy formula a correct implementation? If not, what is the correct implementation?

Comment: @XanderHenderson That is kind of true but not entirely. In programming we often split tasks into little pieces. As long as you understand what that part is meant to do you should be able to implement it without any risk. We do that because when a program grows in size, keeping every step of the program in your mind becomes very hard, aswell as mantaining code that doesn't work independantly of other code

Comment: @DavidK yes, it is the correct implementation, and what you pointed out about superscript(i) could be the key.

Comment: "As long as you understand what that part is meant to do" -- yes, but that requires that whoever specified what it is supposed to do understood how it fits in the larger context and specified it accurately and completely.

Comment: "As long as you understand what that part is meant to do..."  Exactly.  Understanding what it is meant to do means understanding the context in which it is meant to run.

Comment: The main problem here is how "*" is implemented in Numpy. Here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication) you can see that it is implemented as elementwise (or columnwise in case of matrices) multiplication. You just have to differ between mathematical formula, where usually all notations are standard, and actual code where each symbol has its own implementation

Comment: @Exodd Im sorry if I was unclear, yes, * is elementwise multiplication in numpy, but my concern is how to interpret the mathmathical formula, I can translate it to code as long as I understand which type of multiplication the mathmathical formula is refering to.

Comment: and I answered, since the mathematical formula (NOT the code) is always standard and always follow the same rules

Comment: @HappilyCoding The formula is presented to us with zero context, hence it is quite difficult to understand what is meant.  I think that DavidK explained the likely meaning (i.e. that the superscripts are indices), but it is quite hard to know what the authors meant without seeing the rest of the paper.